# Unable to set default Python to 3.x on MacOS Monterey

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

I have followed instructions as given on [How to use pyenv to run multiple versions of Python on a Mac](https://opensource.com/article/20/4/pyenv), and have followed each step.

1. `$ brew install pyenv`
2. `pyenv install 3.9.9`
3. Export path to zshrc via `echo 'PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc`
4. `pyenv global 3.9.9`

After this, when I run `python -V`, I expect to see `Python 3.9.9` as the output. Instead, I see `Python 2.7.18`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: IIRC python 3 executable on a Mac is `python3`, not `python`. What do you get when you run `pythom3 -V`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That is not at all the case when you use `pyenv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After #4 in your list, did you `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think this is unclear at all. The OP asks if they missed something, and this is what they missed. (It should probably not be phrased as a question, though.)

Comment: That seems to be the trick!